# Interleaving function definitions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a couple pattern-matching functions that recurse on each other, and I would like to be able to interleave their definitions like

```
recA [pattern ...] = [.. something that might call recB with the next pattern ..]
recB [pattern ...] = ...
recA [other ...]   = ...
...b
```

etc. Is this possible? Is there some more idiomatic alternative?

Comment: Pattern matching is done on data and structure. Your example doesn't explain concretely why you can't have recA and recB defined separately. Where does the `standard` Haskell code fail in your scenario?

Comment: Have you tried to make a small example program that does this? What was the result?

Comment: The idea is that the first line (indirectly) calls the second line, which calls the third line, etc. in a mutually-recursive fashion, so it makes more sense (to me) to have them in that order.

Comment: @Boris: it's not allowed, the compiler considers it to be redefining the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Haskell 2010 report, section 4.4.3.1 *Function Bindings*](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-800004.4) says that

> Note that all clauses defining a function must be contiguous, and the number of patterns in each clause must be the same.

So you can't interleave `recA` and `recB` as in your example.

There's no theoretical reason (that I can see) why the compiler shouldn't be able to group the various clauses together; I suspect this rule was introduced to guard against human error and confusion. As a silly example, what's wrong with the following?

```
function1 [] = "a"
functionl (x:xs) = "b"
function1 (x:y:xs) = "c"
```